# Remover espaços em branco ao contar Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho esse código:

```js
function contar() {
  var num_caracteres;
  num_caracteres = document.form1.txtTexto.value.length;
  document.getElementById("contador").innerHTML = num_caracteres;
  setTimeout("contar()", 100);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="form2" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="txtTexto" id="txtTexto" onkeypress="contar()"/>
      </label>
    <p><label id="contador"></label></p>
  </form>
</body>
```

Como fazer para ele não contar os espaços em branco digitados?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta usar `.replace(/\s/g,'')` do [Regex](http://regexr.com/) no `value` do seu Input, sendo assim ele removera os espaços em branco.
Regex tirado [dessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623231/remove-all-white-spaces-from-text).

```js
function contar(e) {
    var num_caracteres;
    num_caracteres = document.form1.txtTexto.value.replace(/\s/g,'').length;
    document.getElementById("contador").innerHTML = num_caracteres;
    document.getElementById("contadorInput").value = num_caracteres;
    setTimeout("contar()", 100);

}
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="form2" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <label>
  <input type="text" name="txtTexto" id="txtTexto" onkeypress="contar(event)"/>
  </label>
    <p>Label: <label id="contador"></label></p>
    
    <p>Input <input type="text"  id="contadorInput" /></p>
    
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: e para exibir em um input ao inves da label?

Comment: @BetinhoSilva pronto ! exemplo com label e com input

Answer (score 1):

Antes de contar a quantidade, você pode remover os caracteres em branco com expressão regular:

`num_caracteres = document.form1.txtTexto.value.replace(/ /g, '').length;`

Comment: e para exibir em um input ao inves da label?

Comment: basta selecionar um elemento do tipo input e atribuir um value para ele: document.getElementById("elemento-input").value = num_caracteres;

Answer (score 0):

Use o [*replace*](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/jsref_replace.asp) para remover os espaços:

```
function contar() {
   var textoSemEspacos = document.form1.txtTexto.value.replace(' ', '');
   var num_caracteres = textoSemEspacos.length;
   document.getElementById("contador").innerHTML = num_caracteres;
   setTimeout("contar()", 100);
}
```